# Characters appear in the order as i click

Tags: android, button, textview

For example. There is picture on the top of the screen below that there are some empty boxes and below the boxes there are some buttons. Every button has a character for text("a","c","t"). You click on a button and the button's text appear in the box. You can click them in the order you want to but the answer is "cat" so when you put the characters in the correct order then you got a toast.

I tried to do it with TextViews and Buttons. I can make the button disappear when i click on it and a textview appear in the same time. But every textview has a fix place on the screen, so i need to put every character in every box invisible and when i click on the "c" character it appear in the first box and the other "c" characters stay invisible. But if i click on the "a" first, then it appears in the second box because there is too much variation to do all. I'm not good at explaining but if anyone has an idea how to do that easier please response!

Here is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{

Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;

TextView tg1;
TextView tg2;
TextView tg3;

TextView to1;
TextView to2;
TextView to3;

TextView tl1;
TextView tl2;
TextView tl3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bg);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bo);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bl);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);

    tg1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tg1);
    tg2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tg2);
    tg3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tg3);

    to1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.to1);
    to2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.to2);
    to3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.to3);

    tl1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tl1);
    tl2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tl2);
    tl3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tl3);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     switch(v.getId()) {
     case R.id.bg:
         b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         tg1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         tg2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         tg3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
       break;
     case R.id.bo:
         b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
         to2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         to1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         to3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 

       break;
     case R.id.bl:
         b3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         tl3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         tl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         tl1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
   }
}
```

}

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="hu.szada.gombokelso.MainActivity"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tl1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:text="l"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bo"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="86dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="o" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bl"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bg"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bg"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="l" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bg"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bo"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="g" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tg1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tl"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tl"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tl"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:text="g" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/to1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tl"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tl"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tl"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:text="o" />
```

/// Second

```
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/to2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tl1"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tl1"
     android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl1"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:visibility="invisible"
     android:text="o" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tg2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/to2"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/to2"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/to2"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:visibility="invisible"
     android:text="g" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tl2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/to2"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/to2"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/to2"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:visibility="invisible"
     android:text="l" />

 /// Third


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tg3"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/to2"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/to2"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bl"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:visibility="invisible"
       android:text="g" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tl3"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tg3"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tg3"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tg3"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:visibility="invisible"
       android:text="l" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/to3"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tg3"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tg3"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl3"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:visibility="invisible"
       android:text="o" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try a slightly different approach.

If I understand you correctly, you want to "type" a word out using given lettered buttons. Like one of those hangman style games.

Why not append the text views on the fly.

Something like

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    //Grab the surrounding layout for the textviews
    GridView answerGrid = (GridView)getViewById(R.id.answerGrid);

    //Get the text that was on the button
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String btnText = b.getText().toString();

    //Make a text view with text
    TextView txt = new TextView();
    text.setText(btnText);

    //Append to text view container
    answerGrid.addView(txt);

    //Invisible button
    b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Haven't tested to see if this is perfect, but its a start.

=====

I've looked at your xml

Why not use GridViews?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                ....>
    <GridView android:id="@+id/answerGrid"
              ....>
         <!-- Put nothing here. This is for answers -->
    </GridView>

    <GridView android:id="@+id/lettersGrid"
              android:layout_below="answerGrid"
              ....>
        <!-- Buttons in here -->
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This way you can customise the number of rows/columns based on the length of the word you're playing with. And GridView will automatically give you a neat layout and spacing.

Have a look at the [GridView doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) and get it customised the way you want it.

See my edits above for the Java code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and yes you understand me , i'd like to do it like in the hangman style games. I post my xml maybe it can help.

Comment: Glad to hear it, and yes the XML would help me make a more specific answer.

Comment: I'm trying to do it with your code but i dont understand your first step with the layout. Can you explain that please?

Comment: The first line is just getting a reference to part of your layout so later we can tell android where to put the TextViews. See my edits, hopefully clearer with the XML.

Comment: Thank you very much! Finally i have some time to try it and it works!

Comment: You are very welcome. Out of interest, you used GridLayout not GridView right?